# QJsonDocument::fromRawData(const char *data, int size) data has to be aligned to a 4 byte boundary

Tags: c++, qt

```
void test()
{
    QFile f("..\\data\\NAVHistory2.txt");
    if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        return;
    }
    QByteArray data = f.readAll();
    int iLeft = data.indexOf('[');
    int iRight = data.lastIndexOf(']');

    QJsonDocument::fromRawData(data.data() + iLeft, iRight - iLeft + 1);// got error

}
```

I want to cut a part of `QByteArray` and send it to a `QJsonDocument`. The simplest way is to use `QByteArray::mid` and create a new copy of `QByteArray`. And `QJsonDocument::fromJson(QByteArray)` works well.

However, it only needs to cut a small part of data away. So to create a new `QBytedata` would lost performance. There is a better way `QJsonDocument::fromRawData(char*)`. But I got an error:

`QJsonDocument::fromRawData: data has to have 4 byte alignment`

I looked up the Qt document for [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromRawData). It says `data has to be aligned to a 4 byte boundary.`
[Qt source](https://gitlab.com/pteam/pteam-qtbase/commit/9633459274f99487360bcc7c7e7c593c4ac98ce2)

My application is a x64 project, so the `char*` is a 8-byte boundary. How do I get through it?

Comment: Is the data you want located inside `data` on a 4-byte boundary? I.e. is the string itself that you want to extract aligned in the way that `fromJson` expects? What are the offsets to `[` and `]` inside the string (i.e. what are the values of `iLeft` and `iRight`)?

Comment: Is your text file really a "binary encoded JSON document"? You need that for the raw variant. Seems unlikely if you need to strip parts of it out like this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, iLeft is 67, iRight is 559093. I outputed it to another file, looks good. `QFile f2; f2.write(data.data() + iLeft, iRight - iLeft + 1);`

Comment: @Mat, Just a normal text file.

Comment: The offset `67` is definitely not 4-byte aligned, which means the pointer resulting from `data.data() + iLeft` will not be 4-byte aligned either. Which is why you have a problem.

Comment: "copying a small part of data" will have basically immeasurable effect in performance. I wouldn't worry about it, unless you do this at least several thousand times per second... In which case JSON seems a bad choice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

- Just take the copy. Quick and easy.
- If you don't need anything else from `data`, just use `data.remove(0, iLeft)` to make your JSON snippet start at the beginning of the `QByteArray` (which will be  aligned to at least 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Qt document:

`It assumes data contains a binary encoded JSON document.`

The data should be a binary encoded. My document is just a normal text. So it doesn't work. I didn't noticed that before.

It seems I have to use `QJsonDocument::fromJson`.